# data copy from oracle to postgres using hibernate

Tags: oracle, postgresql, hibernate

Am new to hiberante JPA. I am working on oracle to postgres migration and we are not using aws dms service for data migration. We would like to move ahead with Java for copying tables which have more than 1 million records. I have problem for below scenario.

Table A - Oracle
Table B - PostGres

Am extracting records from Oracle using ScrollableResults. Once i have the data from Oracle, i need to loop up a value in postgres database for data from Oracle before performing insert into postgres database.

I thought first @ColumnTransformer will help but it is not helping as i dont know how to reference data from oracle on ColumnTransformer expression.

So finally went ahead with writing normal insert query with values and subquery for lookup. Also set hibernate.jdbc.batch_size to 100.

I executed the program in this way and it took 5 mins for 10k records which i feel is slow.

is there any other solution for this problem to improve the performance.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: If you only need to move data from Oracle to Postgres, you can use a [`foreign data wrapper`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-foreign-data.html)

Comment: thank you. But we are using aws aurora rds db and have very less control over the db since it is amazon maintained. Also our organization is not allowing to connect from postgres to oracle without TLS/SSL encryption since data is very sensitive as oracle db on premise. And our DBAs are not encouraging connecting to oracle db from postgres db.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I solved it by storing postgres lookup table in list object then performing search in lookup table list object before performing insert. Now the speed is good.